# How To Handle ui-router Between Modules in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, module, angular-ui-router

In angular it's nice that you can split functionality between modules to support multiple apps. Like if I had 2 apps and they both could use the same "User" module I could just include that module in both apps.

```
angular.module('User', []); // include a bunch of user stuff
angular.module('App1', ['User']);
angular.module('App2', ['User']);
```

Which isn't new to anyone. But with ui-router I also would like to define states in a module.

```
angular.module('User').config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('user', {})
  .state('user.profile', {});
});
```

The issue is that I want `user` and `user.profile` as a child state of one of the apps states. Something like- `root.users.user.profile`. But I don't want the `User` module to have to be aware of that. The `User` module should only define states in it's small view of the world.

Is it possible to append already defined states? How do you write states in modules like this so that it stays modular?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is completely possible to define states and use it in another module. All you need to take care is that there should not be any circular dependencies in your modules. And the correct modules are being injected as the dependency in another modules.

So you can do something like following :

```
angular.module('App1', ['User']).config(function($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
      .state('root', {})
      .state('root.users', {});
})

angular.module('User').config(function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider.state('root.users.user', {})
      .state('root.users.user.profile', {});
    });
```

I hope this will help :)

Comment: Well the issue is `users.user` may or may not be a child of `root`. I want to make that the modular part. I'd like for `User` to define `users.user` and the app to *append* that state to `root` somehow.